# Store results of std::stack .pop() method into a variable

Tags: c++, stack

I'd like to do the following:

```
std::stack <int> s;
int h = 0;
s.push(2);
h = s.pop();
```

Such as to have `h` hold the value 2. When I try my method, I get “void value not ignored as it ought to be”.

Is this not the intention of the `.pop()` method? What is the preferred way to do this?

Comment: `h = s.top(); `

Comment: No, you're not an idiot - this is a very non-intuitive design decision by the C++ committee. Most of us consider popping from a stack to return a value.

Comment: @MarkRansom the rationale is for exception safety. See my comment on Kerrek SB's answer.

Comment: @BrianNeal, I knew there was a good reason even though I couldn't remember it. It's still non-intuitive.

Comment: When it comes to exception safety, things rarely seem intuitive.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The standard library containers separate `top()` and `pop()`: `top()` returns a reference to the top element, and `pop()` removes the top element. (And similarly for `back()`/`pop_back()` etc.).

There's a good reason for this separation, and not have `pop` remove the top element *and* return it: One guiding principle of C++ is that you don't pay for what you don't need. A single function would have no choice but to return the element by value, which may be undesired. Separating concerns gives the user the most flexibility in how to use the data structure. (See note #3 in [the original STL documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stack.html).)

(As a curiousum, you may notice that for a *concurrent* container, a `pop`-like function is actually *forced* to remove and return the top value atomically, since in a concurrent context, there is no such notion as "being on top" (or "being empty" for that matter). This is one of the obvious examples of how concurrent data structures take a significant performance hit in order to provide their guarantees.)

Comment: I'd like to add more weight to the stance that `pop()` returning a value is a bad idea. Even if `pop()` returned a value efficiently, users that didn't use the return value could still pay a price: the copy-constructor could throw an exception. We wouldn't even be able to guarantee the simple act of popping off an unused value would work! (Obviously ignoring that failure of a possibility that is a throwing destructor.)

Comment: @GManNickG: Good point, exception safety is always important to keep in mind!

Comment: Yes, exception safety is the primary reason for the separation. Otherwise, if `pop()` returned the value, and an exception is thrown by the copy constructor, you may not be able to guarantee that the stack is in the same state it was before calling `pop()`. By splitting the functionality across two functions you can have much stronger guarantees about exception safety.

Comment: @BrianNeal, there are ways to design `pop` such that an exception caused by a copy constructor still leaves the stack in a good state. As for paying for what you don't need, there could have been an alternate method `remove` that removed the top element without returning it.

Comment: @MarkRansom this exact issue is explained in detail in Herb Sutter's _Exceptional C++_ book, item 8.

Comment: Basically, if the copy constructor throws, your stack has already changed state, but the item is lost forever.

Comment: How would you move the top without copying?

Comment: @zehelvion: "move" or "remove"? The former with `std::move`, the latter with `pop`.

Comment: While this design is valid, it's shortsighted 'cuz 1)removing and returning is the standard operation in stack-based algorithms 2)the definition of "pop" is "remove and return". It would make more sense to make both a version that returns and the one that doesn't, not requiring programmers to type two operations each time or resort to a macro or a subclass every time.

Comment: pop is a misnomer then. It does not algorithmically pop from the stack. Reasoning for the behavior aside.

Comment: But doesn't the compiler sometimes optimizes return values to be returned as references instead? Wouldn't this solve the issue?

Comment: @mFeinstein: No, I think you're thinking of something else. No kind of optimisation can help with the fact that if you want to remove an element from the container and still talk about that element, you need to make some sort of copy, whereas access of the existing element via `top` does not require _any_ copying.

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
h = s.top();
```

then after that use(if you want to remove the most recent value otherwise do nothing)

```
 s.pop();
```

It works the same way!!

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use `s.top()` to store the element and then pop it using

```
s.pop().
```

use

```
int h=s.top();
s.pop()
```

instead of

```
int h=s.pop()
```

You cannot directly assign `s.pop()` to some data type, as `s.pop()` removes element from stack and returns nothing.

Answer (score -5):

`S.pop()` does not return any value. Because `pop()` is void function. 
If you want to see the top of the stack then it  will be `S.top()`. If you store this value then write `value = S.top()`.

Comment: May I ask why you are answering a 3 year old question with an answer that doesn't provide any more insight into the question than the accepted answer does?