# C++, stack and pointers of struct

Tags: c++, struct, stack

Hello I have a problem with pointer on struct in a stack.

I have a stack of struct:

```
stack<Somethink*> stack1;
```

And i want to push and pop array of "Somethink"

```
void Search(Somethink* array_Somethink, int s, int d,) {

stack1.push(&(array_Somethink[s]));  // 

while (stack1.size() != 0) {
    int  i = 0;

    array_Somethink[i] = *(stack1.pop()); // this return a error
    i++;
   }
}
```

I hope someone can give me a tip, how to properly push and pop from this stack

Thank you :D

Comment: Post a [MCVE] please, including the verbatim error messages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store results of std::stack .pop() method into a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206242/store-results-of-stdstack-pop-method-into-a-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void Search(Somethink* array_Somethink, int s, int d,) {

stack1.push(&(array_Somethink[s]));  // 

while (!stack1.empty()) {
    int  i = 0;

    array_Somethink[i] = *(stack1.top());
    stack1.pop();
    i++;
   }
}
```

My modified code assumes, you have "owning" pointers to the elements on the stack somewhere else. If that is not the case, you would end with memory leaks here, as the pointers in the stack become dangling objects (leaks).

In order to avoid the potential for memory leaks, here, it might be a good idea if you used `std::shared_ptr<Somethink>` instead of raw pointers. Then, your stack would become a `std::stack< std:shared_ptr<Somethink> >`.

For details on std::stack operations `empty(),pop(),top()`, see [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) in the usual place.

There, you will find explanations such as this:

> std::stack::top
>     C++  Containers library  std::stack 
>   reference top();
>   const_reference top() const;
>   Returns reference to the top element in the stack. This is the most recently pushed element. This element will be removed on a call to pop(). Effectively calls c.back().

Comment: Meh, code only. Add some explanation about `pop()` signature, and what `top()` actually does.

Comment: Can you tell me what does the .top() do? 
This works and it is correct answer ! :)

Answer (score 0):

`top` will return a pointer to the struct and you are trying to assign it to an instance of the struct. Basically you are trying to assign a pointer to `Somethink` to a position in an array of `Somethink`'s

Comment: AFAIR `pop()` returns nothing (`void`), but `top()`/`front()` does respectively.

Comment: Thank you for this, it was very usefull :)