# Stack combine both pop() and top()?

Tags: c++, stack, std

With a `std::stack` we use `pop()` to extract last member and `top()` to get its value. Is there any shortcut to do both actions together (Get value of last member and kick it out)?

Comment: yes I am @FrançoisAndrieux

Comment: Short answer, no.  You have to handle the empty case (the stack is empty) so it's not simple

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store results of std::stack .pop() method into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206242/store-results-of-stdstack-pop-method-into-a-variable)

Comment: No in c++ we dont have such method to do both in one method.

Comment: "is there any shortcut to do both actions together" - does it really matter? Your friendly optimizing compiler is almost certainly going to collapse the two lines of code you write, to a minimum of optimal instructions (once you compile your code with optimizations *enabled*).

Comment: @NathanOliver what empty case? it's safe to call top and pop on empty stack

Comment: See also [Why doesn't std::queue::pop return value.?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25035691/10077). Hmm, to hammer or not to hammer?

Comment: No, it is not safe to call top or pop on an empty stack.  doing so causes undefined behavior

Comment: You can make your own freestanding `poptop` function that does the top and the pop for you in one fell swoop.

Comment: @NathanOliver, Since it's UB anyway, you don't really have to worry about that case if mimicking the `stack` requirements. An implementation that does `auto& elem = top(); pop(); return elem;` would have the same UB characteristics as `top`.

Comment: "There are cases where it would be UB" has never been a roadblock for the standard library. The standard library very well could implement a feature to do `top` and `pop` together. It could be safely used anywhere `top` and `pop` can be safely used and it couldn't be used where `top` or `pop` couldn't. Though the commit likely won't. It doesn't seem in line with the current language design philosophies.

Comment: Can `pop()` and `top()` be made well defined if the underlying container's `back()` member function is well defined for an empty container? If `my_container::back()` throws on an empty container, would `std::stack<my_container>{}.top()` definitely be well defined?

Comment: @cdhowie, Oops, I wasn't thinking very hard, focusing on moving out of the function instead of moving out of the stack.

Answer (score 5):

The reason that `pop()` does not return the value of the popped element is that doing that is not exception-safe. If the copy constructor for the returned value throws an exception the value has been lost. It’s been removed from the stack but it hasn’t been copied. There’s no way to get it back. If you don’t care about that, you can write your “shortcut” function in the obvious way: copy the `top()` object, `pop()` the stack, and return the value.

Answer (score 3):

There is no technical reason that this couldn't be done.  It can be implemented simply enough as a utility:

```
template <typename T>
auto pop_value(T & stack) {
    auto v = std::move(stack.top());
    stack.pop();
    return v;
}
```

If using C++11 where return type deduction is not available, replace `auto` with `typename T::value_type`.

Comment: Like the usage of `std::move`, its quite easy to "forget" that `top` returns a reference (not a value by copy)

Comment: @ShmilTheCat I'm not sure what you're saying. Are you pointing out a defect in my code, or making a passing observation about why this kind of function is useful?

Comment: No defect !, just highlighting the usefulness of your code, and your meticulous usage of `move` semantics, which, IMO, might be overlooked by many people

Comment: Ah cool. I think I was confused by "like" in your first message. I read it "similar to the usage of `std::move`" and couldn't figure out the meaning, but now I think you meant "I like the usage of `std::move`". Note that without the move this code would still be safe, it would just make a redundant copy (and couldn't be used at all with non-copyable types).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any shortcut to do both actions together

No.

But you can write a function that calls both and use it as your "shortcut".

Answer (score 1):

top() - only returns the element but doesn't remove it.
pop() - only removes the element but doesn't return anything.

There is no such method where it remove and return the removed element.

Make sure to do an empty check when doing top or pop as it causes error. Please have empty check before doing any of these actions.